# google dialogflow how to query subset of knowledgebases in a mega bot

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a mega bot eg: **projectID_stage with id=stage-aahedc** and there are two sub agents: **projectID_automated id=stageautomated-spiccu** and projectC.
the projectID_automated has knowledge base enabled. and it's included in the projectID_stage.

**The problem:**

When I trying to do a detectIntent request with some part of knowledgebase set.  it failed because of permission denied.

the code is similar with - https://github.com/googleapis/java-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/DetectIntentKnowledge.java (except I added two knowledge names)

```
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.*;
import com.google.common.collect.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DetectIntentTexts {

    // DialogFlow API Detect Intent sample with text inputs.
    public static Map<String, QueryResult> detectIntentTexts(
            String projectId, List<String> texts, String sessionId, String languageCode, String... kbNames)
            throws IOException {
        Map<String, QueryResult> queryResults = Maps.newHashMap();
        // Instantiates a client
        try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {
            // Set the session name using the sessionId (UUID) and projectID (my-project-id)
            SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
            System.out.println("Session Path: " + session.toString());
            // Detect intents for each text input
            for (String text : texts) {
                // Set the text (hello) and language code (en-US) for the query
                TextInput.Builder textInput =
                        TextInput.newBuilder().setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode);

                // Build the query with the TextInput
                QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();


                QueryParameters queryParameters =
                        QueryParameters.newBuilder().addKnowledgeBaseNames(kbNames[0])
                                .addKnowledgeBaseNames(kbNames[1]).build();

                DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest =
                        DetectIntentRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setSession(session.toString())
                                .setQueryInput(queryInput)
                                .setQueryParams(queryParameters)
                                .build();
                // Performs the detect intent request
                DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(detectIntentRequest);

                // Display the query result
                QueryResult queryResult = response.getQueryResult();

                System.out.println("====================");
                System.out.format("Query Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getQueryText());
                System.out.format(
                        "Detected Intent: %s (confidence: %f)\n",
                        queryResult.getIntent().getDisplayName(), queryResult.getIntentDetectionConfidence());
                System.out.format(
                        "Fulfillment Text: '%s'\n",
                        queryResult.getFulfillmentMessagesCount() > 0
                                ? queryResult.getFulfillmentMessages(0).getText()
                                : "Triggered Default Fallback Intent");

                queryResults.put(text, queryResult);
            }
        }
        return queryResults;
    }
}
// [END dialogflow_detect_intent_text]
```

and the main function is like below:

```
        String projectID_automated = "stageautomated-spiccu";
        String projectID_stage = "stage-aahedc";
        String finalProjectID = projectID_stage;

        String sessionID = "123456789";
        String language = "en-US";
        List<String> text = Arrays.asList("is it safe for my family and pets");

        // when you trying to list out the kbs....
        // listKbs(projectID);
        // projects/<Project ID>/knowledgeBases/<Knowledge Base ID>`
        String kb1 = "pest control-1", kb2 = "pest control-2";
        String full1 = "projects/" + projectID_automated + "/knowledgeBases/MTE0NTc1ODUxNjIwNTM3NDY2ODg";
        String full2 = "projects/" + projectID_automated + "/knowledgeBases/Njg0NTg5OTE0MzYyNjM1ODc4NA";
        Map<String, QueryResult> r = DetectIntentTexts.detectIntentTexts(finalProjectID, text, sessionID, language, full1, full2);
        System.out.println(r);
```

When using the projectID_automated for full1 and full2, it failed with below error:

```
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project 'stageautomated-spiccu' in knowledge_base_names does not match project 'stage-aahedc' in session.
```

When using the projectID_stage for full1 and full2,

```
    String full1 = "projects/" + projectID_stage + "/knowledgeBases/MTE0NTc1ODUxNjIwNTM3NDY2ODg";
    String full2 = "projects/" + projectID_stage + "/knowledgeBases/Njg0NTg5OTE0MzYyNjM1ODc4NA";
```

it failed with below error in the query result

```
diagnostic_info {
  fields {
    key: "knowledge_connector_error"
    value {
      string_value: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: UNAUTHORIZED: You can\'t query KnowledgeBase under project: stage-aahedc, which is different than your agent project: stageautomated-spiccu"
    }
  }
```

**Environment details**

```
dialogflow#detectIntent
OS type and version: macos 10
Java version: jdk11
dialogflow version(s): dialogflow es + 'com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-dialogflow-v2beta1:0.99.5'
and 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:4.1.5'
```

Comment: I looked into documentation, I haven't found anything about using "shared" knowledge base, but on the other hand I haven't found anything that it cannot be done that way. I think you should raise in on [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support#issues)

Comment: @vitooh Thanks, I added an issue here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200975241